# Equation to calculate a smooth line given an irregular time series?

Tags: data-visualization, smoothing

I'm trying to visualize a set of data that represents human body mass over time, taken from (usually) daily weighings.

Because body mass tends to fluctuate +/- 3 pounds based on hydration I would like to draw a strongly smoothed line graph to minimize the fluctuation.

Any help on what the equation would look like is much appreciated, or even just some names/links to send me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**
I need to code the visualization in Javascript, so I need understanding of the math involved, rather than a library that will do it for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several methods of estimating a smooth trend line. Some of the most popular are:

- Moving average smoother
- Local linear regression (loess being a popular robust implementation)
- Smoothing splines
- Regression splines (of various flavors).

My preference is to use **penalized regression splines** which you can fit using the [mgcv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/) package in R.

**Update**: since you want to code it yourself, you might find it simplest to start with a moving average smoother (for each day, just take an average of observations from the k days on either side with k to be selected so as to give the appropriate level of smoothness).

Comment: What about the kalman filter and/or smoother? Where does that fit in?